# Should I call NSSavePanel runModal method only from main thread?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, nssavepanel

I have weird, though rare, crashes in my application.

I suspect that it happens because `runModal` of `NSSavePanel` is called in a thread different from the main thread.

Am I correct that it might be the cause for the crashes?

Answer (score 1):

See the Threading Programming Guide from Apple:

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/Introduction/Introduction.html

"Thread-Unsafe Classes: 
NSWindow and all of its descendants."

NSSavePanel is a descendant of NSWindow.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

I've had crashes calling `runModal` on the wrong thread. `performSelectorOnMainThread` is often useful to fix this.

Comment: Does `performSelectorOnMainThread` work on desktop osx? I cant find it anywhere in the docs, do you know where it is? Thx!

Comment: Haven't worked on OSX in a while, but maybe this?: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/performSelectorOnMainThread:withObject:waitUntilDone:

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, all access to UI elements should happen from the main thread, also sometimes referred to as the UI thread.

So I'd say yes, you should open it from the main thread.

As to whether that is the source of your crashes is hard to tell. My modest experience tells me that crashes can be caused by all sorts of things...