# Standard library containing dispatch_get_main_queue (GCD)

Tags: objective-c, macos, grand-central-dispatch, core-foundation

I'm trying to run some NSWindow functions from another thread on OSX. I am doing this via ctypes so need to find the library files.

`dispatch_sync` I found in `libc.dylib` but I can't find `dispatch_get_main_queue`, does anyone know the library that is in? Is it not in `libc`? I thought to use this based on here: [Objective C Multi thread NSWindow alternative?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31630725/1828637)

I also couldn't find the docs of the types used on opensource.apple can someone also help me find that for this `Dispatch` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dispatch_get_main_queue()` is an inline function, so it doesn't end up in any library. It's compiled into every [Objective-]C/C++ file that uses it.

It compiles down to just `(dispatch_queue_t)&_dispatch_main_q`, more or less. That is, there's a global variable `_dispatch_main_q` and `dispatch_get_main_queue()` just returns its address, type cast to `dispatch_queue_t`.

On my 10.9.5 system, `_dispatch_main_q` is exported by /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib.

Comment: Thanks so much Ken for such a fast answer! I was struggling with this sucker for like 12 hours! On and off :P